# Problems install Kafka Connector on Confluent CLI

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-cloud

I'm trying to install a sink connector to an s3 bucket using the tutorial on Confluent's website here https://docs.confluent.io/cloud/current/connectors/cc-s3-sink.html#step-4-load-the-properties-file-and-create-the-connector

but it seems to be outdated - i've created my config file but this prompt

```
confluent connect cluster create --config-file <file-name>.json
```

returns an error 'Error: unknown flag: --config-file'

and it seems like the create command has also been deprecated?

Anyone know a way to go about this? Thanks

Comment: I would suggest using REST API rather than the `confluent` CLI